# Question about fluid flow through a funnel or cone

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I am an MD, I am studying the fluid flow of the tears through the tears duct system of the eye. The newer view suggests that the first part of the system is a funnel or a cone. I cant seem to understand (without equations), what are the main advantages of fluid flow through a funnel?

Comment: I do not think this is a question for physics. The advantages come from the use of a funnel for example: large area generated fluid gathered into a small output; but this depends on a biology model, i.e. how the tears are produced .

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 2):

The primary characteristic of flow through a funnel is that the ratio of the velocities of flow in one end and out the other is scaled by the ratio of the cross-sectional areas of the two ends. Slow flow in the big end is transformed into fast flow at the small end. A funnel is also called a *bernoulli transformer* for this reason.

Comment: Thank you for your answer